# Xamarin Android - API 27 RequestPermission

Tags: xamarin.android, android-permissions

I am using the following code to request permissions for FineLocation/CoarseLocation and Camera:

```
protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            txt_TrashSubmitDescriptionTitle = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_TrashSubmitDescriptionTitle);

            var c = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == (int)Permission.Granted;
            var y = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) == (int)Permission.Granted;
            var z = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted;

            if (c && y && z)
            {
                StartLocationService();


            }
            else
            {
                var requiredPermissions = new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.Camera };
                if (GeneralFunctions.CheckShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleForPermissions(this, requiredPermissions))
                {
                    // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
                    // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
                    // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.

                    Snackbar.Make(txt_TrashSubmitDescriptionTitle,
                                   Resource.String.permission_location_rationale,
                                   Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                            .SetAction(Resource.String.ok, new Action<Android.Views.View>(delegate (Android.Views.View x) { ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 2); })).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 2);
                }
            }
        }
```

This function is to check if the PermissionRadiale should be shown:

```
public static bool CheckShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleForPermissions(Activity _activity, string[] requiredPermissions)
        {
            bool returnBool = false;
            foreach(string _permission in requiredPermissions)
            {
                returnBool = ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(_activity, _permission);
            }
            return returnBool;
        }
```

The function OnResume keeps getting called over and over with no specific error and I dont know why.

Does someone know why the OnResume keep getting called?

Comment: If you want to request Runtime Permissions .You can refer this guide https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: Did you see my code-snippets? Its the same code...

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that you have the permissions set in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Without those, the application, as you have it with the code in OnResume(), will go into an infinite OnResume() loop.  At least it did in my test app where I'm targeting Android 9.0.

Once those are set, the code works well enough *if* the user grants all the privileges.  But, I still would move the RequestPermissions() code out of OnResume() to either OnCreate() or OnStart().  One reason is because the user could check "Don't Ask Again", in which case it could result in an endless loop.

For some background... when the RequestPermissions() dialog is shown, your activity fires OnPause(), and when the RequestPermissions dialog is closed, OnRequestPermissionsResult() and OnResume() are raised.  This also appears to happen in those cases where RequestPermissions() is fired, but no dialog is visible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I need these Permissions to ensure that the app will work properly. So thats the way i want it to be...

Comment: Yep, I’m just suggesting that you ensure the permissions are set in the Manifest, as a loop like you experienced can happen without them, and then move your code out of OnResume (e.g., OnStart).  Or, if you really want, you can keep them in OnResume, but your app runs the risk of an infinite loop in some situations, such as the user clicking “Don’t Ask Again” in the permissions request.  There are other posts on this site that have more details on why you should not have permissions checking code in OnResume.  Good luck!